# mysql Setting field with multiple column as comma separated value

Tags: mysql

my raw query look something like this-

```
UPDATE main,category,sub_category
SET main.biz_keyword = (category.category','sub_category.sub_cat_name','main.biz_keyword)
```

so the result something like `main.biz_keyword='Doctor,General Physician,Physician'`
I know this is wrong query but you got the Idea what I am looking for,
So my question is that I can do this by single query?

Comment: What column do you want to update?

Comment: biz_keyword in main table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to have a look at using [CONCAT_WS(separator,str1,str2,...)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)

> CONCAT_WS() stands for Concatenate With Separator and is a special
>   form of CONCAT(). The first argument is the separator for the rest of
>   the arguments. The separator is added between the strings to be
>   concatenated.

Answer (score 0):

is this something you want to achieve?

```
Update TableName
set biz_keyword = category.category + ',' + sub_category.sub_cat_name + ',' + main.biz_keyword
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for something like this?

```
UPDATE
    main
SET
    biz_keyword = CONCAT_WS(', ',
        (SELECT category FROM category WHERE ... ),
        (SELECT sub_cat_name FROM sub_category WHERE ... ),
        biz_keyword)
```